# How to start a foreground service from broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

I am creating a battery related app.
I have created a broadcast receiver declared in manifest :

Manifest :

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver :

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "The device is charging", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
            Toast.makeText(context, "The device is not charging", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add a foreground notification (like [this](http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/) one)
But how should i add it from broadcast receiver?
(i.e how can i start a service from broadcast receiver?)

Answer (score 5):

in onReceive() start service:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} else {
   context.startService(intent); 
}
```

And in service onCreate() make something like that:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   startForeground(1, new Notification());
}
```

Some manufacturers have backport on Android N these new background limitations, that's why you might to support this api too.

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 Yes, you can make *startForeground* in *onStartCommand* aswell. In some cases you should do it. If you make bound service (through *bindService*), you can't make this service foreground untill *startService* and in *onStartCommand* make it *startForeground*. So as you can see, in some cases this is a only way to make service as foreground :D

Comment: What does it actually mean to bind a service? Sorry I am a bit new.

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Comment: `startForegroundService` works on `Build.VERSION_CODES.O` and above, not `Build.VERSION_CODES.N`

Comment: @OmarShawky that's true, but as i said "Some manufacturers have backport on Android N these new background limitations, that's why you might to support this api too."